# How to enable method suggestions for pyspark and numpy in VS code?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, pyspark

I got a python file that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyspark

df_pd = pd.DataFrame()

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame([
    [1, ]
], ["A"])

a = np.arange(10)
```

When I type `df_pd.` and wait after typing the dot VS Code gives me method suggestions like `join`, `pivot` and so on.
[image]

I'd like to have the same for `a` and `df_spark`. However, when I type `a.` or `df_spark.` and wait, no method suggestions will show up.

[image]

Does anybody know how to make method suggestions work for numpy and pyspark?

Additional info:

- VS Code version: 1.58.2
- python extension version: v2021.6.944021595
- pylance extension version: v2021.7.4
- Visual Studio IntelliCode extension version: v1.2.14
- OS: macOS BigSurr version 11.1
- Numpy and pyspark are installed in the environment of the selected interpreter (the same environment in which also pandas is installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has some problems with `Pylance` and `Microsoft` Language Server. They are not smart enough. Could you have a try on `JediLSP` Language Server?

```
"python.languageServer": "JediLSP",
```

Update:

You can try to take 'import pyspark.sql' or 'from pyspark.sql import SparkSession' instead of 'import pyspark'.

It was designed like this. You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1578#issuecomment-884609108) for the explanation of the developer on this design.

Comment: Tried it, but did not work. I have a python file with jupyter code cells (each sell starts with `# %%`). Method suggestion does not work with Microsoft, Pylance or JediLSP in the py file. However, if I run my code cells, an interactive window is opened by vscode at whose bottom I have a section where I can type in and evaluate python code in an interactive shell. There the method suggestion works for all language servers

Comment: @zwithouta Thanks for your response. I have submitted a bug on Github. You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1578) to join the discussion.

Comment: @zwithouta Could you try to take 'import pyspark.sql' or 'from pyspark.sql import SparkSession' instead of 'import pyspark'? And could you check this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1578#issuecomment-884609108)

Comment: Works like a charm! `import pyspark.sql` is sufficient to get suggestions for `spark` and `df_spark`. Thanks for opening the issue on github! However, I still have no idea how we could get the method suggestions for numpy arrays working. I tried to by importing `array` like this `from numpy import array` but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Seems to be a different kind of problem since numpy suggestions also do not work in the interactive window. However IntelliJ/Pycharm make type suggestions, so it is definitely possible.

Comment: @zwithouta It should be work, I test on my computer everything works well. Could you switch the python interpreter and make sure you have installed numpy? And, if it's a little help could you accept this answer and upvote it? thanks a lot, have a good day : ).

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to contain the actual solution, so people searching for it don't have to search in the comments?